# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying this piece of code for hours. I am not able to figure out what my error is.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'mydb')
            or die( "Unable to connect");

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from Users where Fuid='$fbid'",
            MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);


if (empty($rows)) { // if new user . Insert a new record        
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (Fuid,Funame,Ffname,Femail)
            VALUES ('$fbid','$funame','$ffname','$femail')";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);    
}
```

There might be a very small error, but I am just fried up.

Comment: `mysqli_query($conn,$query);` You reversed the parameters the second time.

Comment: remove the or die statement. Add this on a new line after the connection string. If the line fires, fix the connection error. Otherwise, let me know that know error was generated.

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo '<p>Cannot connect to DB: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . '</p>';

Comment: Accidentally posted before I finished that thought :-) See me updated response

Comment: @bansi, if you don't mind your users seeing an error page that looks like the site is broken, nothing

Comment: @Len_D That if statement shows no error.

Comment: add this on a line right after the connect statement:
mysqli_select_db($conn, "dbname"); where dbname is your actual dbname

Comment: @Len_D The database name is already passed as the fourth argument to `mysqli_connect`

Comment: I know. Humor me and try it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to do a lot of things the hard way. Try this instead...

```php
// Set MySQLi to throw exceptions when it encounters an error
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'mydb');
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // or whatever is appropriate

$check = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM `Users` WHERE Fuid = ?');
$check->bind_param('i', $fbid); // assuming $fbid is an integer
$check->execute();
if (!$check->fetch()) {
    $sql  = 'INSERT INTO `Users` (Fuid, Funame, Ffname, Femail) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('isss', $fbid, $funame, $ffname, $femail);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: What you mean by `the hard way`? isn't this the right way!

Comment: i am sure OP of question won't understand this :D as OP doesnt using prepaired statements

Comment: @bansi *"the hard way"* meaning using a `SELECT *` query to simply check existence and executing code without any error checking

Comment: @NullPoiиteя that's why I keep posting answers like this

Comment: @YourCommonSense I appreciate the edit for brevity but I stand by my use of exceptions. You simply can't control user errors in the same way

Comment: Surely you have objections which you can express with words of language

Comment: There is no such thing like "your" use of exceptions. there is just use of exceptions. All you need is to use them in a little smarter way, making your code readable.

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Column 'Fuid' cannot be null' in /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/functions.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/functions.php(14): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/fbconfig.php(3): require('/home/anaad6c3/...') #2 /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/index.php(2): require('/home/anaad6c3/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/functions.php on line 14`

Comment: @user3344070 this error message means $fbid variable is not set.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I meant the use of them (exceptions) in my answer.

Comment: Which assumes I didn't use them in mine. This assumption is obviously wrong. Don't take me for a regular participant of this unlucky tag. I do no harmful edits.

Comment: @YourCommonSense `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/anaad6c3/public_html/demo/functions.php on line 8`

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm well aware of your contributions. What I wasn't aware of is how `mysqli_report` works with `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`. I assumed it merely triggered `E_WARNING` level errors. Thank you

Comment: @user3344070 That doesn't make any sense. If `$conn` was a *non-object*, it would have triggered an error for `$conn->set_charset()`.

Comment: @user3344070 this error is impossible for this code. You have to try is exactly as is and then, if worked, split it to separate files or whatever you want with it.

Comment: @Phil surely it throws an exception for the connect as well. So, it should have been thrown even earlier

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wasn't sure about that as the PHP manual examples for `mysqli_report` still check `connect_errno`. Tested locally and yes, it *should* throw an exception for a bad connection.

Comment: @Dharman done but feel free to make the edits yourself whenever you want. The author can always roll it back if they don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

instead of

```
 mysqli_query($query, $conn);
```

Answer (score -2):

You reversed the parameters!

```
mysqli_query($query, $conn);
```

Should be

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Try this:
Use `mysqli_connect_errno` instead of `die`

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'mydb');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}    

$check = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from Users where Fuid='$fbid'",
            MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);


if (empty($rows)) { // if new user . Insert a new record        
    $query = "INSERT INTO Users (Fuid,Funame,Ffname,Femail)
            VALUES ('$fbid','$funame','$ffname','$femail')";

    mysqli_query($conn,$query);    
}
```

Comment: I used that in previous query `$check = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from Users where Fuid='$fbid'", MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);`
Shows error in this too